# How do I switch keyboard layout programmatically in MacOS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos

how do I switch keyboard layout (AKA input source) programmatically in MacOS X in a Cocoa/Objective C program? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had occasion to try this, but I *think* you want the functions in [text input source services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html). Note that these are Carbon functions, though usable from Cocoa -- you'll need to add the Carbon framework to your project in order to use them.

Comment: You are correct. Also, it's worth noting that that API is not deprecated—it is, in fact, the *modern* replacement for the deprecated Keyboard Layout Services.